# Use jQuery to check if a URL on another domain is 404 or not?

Tags: jquery, cross-site

On the client side using jQuery, I want to know if I can just check if a link URL is valid (i.e. doesn't return a 404).  This link points to another domain, so if I just use $.get() then I end up with a permission issue.  I remember reading something about using a JSONP request, but I don't remember.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution that seems to work (using YQL):

```
$.getJSON("http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?"+
            "q=select%20*%20from%20html%20where%20url%3D%22"+
            encodeURIComponent(url)+
            "%22&format=xml'&callback=?",
    function(data){
      if(data.results[0]){
        // do whatever
      } 
    }
  );
```

Assumes the URL you want to check is in the variable 'url'.

Comment: From the docs at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/  :


If the specified URL is on a remote server, the request is treated as JSONP instead. See the discussion of the jsonp data type in $.ajax() for more details.

Comment: @TahirAkhtar This is using JSONP to ask Yahoo to go and check for you if the page exists. This is like the local proxy solution others have suggested, but using a third party proxy (Yahoo), rather than a local one.

Comment: Ah, thank you very much! you saved me a lot of work! This helps me make a script to check if a URL on another site is dead.

Comment: This code still produces Cross-Origin Request Blocked errors

Comment: @KevinDuke Where? Running that code is giving me no errors on JS console of Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

JSONP works if the server you are calling on can return JSONP formatted response. Which basically means a script that calls a callback function on your page after getting loaded. 
see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#JSONP

In your case it won't work unless the other site is willing to cooperate or you have a proxy script on your own site.

If you want your script to work with sites not under your control, your best bet will be to use a proxy or a iframe hack.

Answer (score 0):

You can't make a request like that to another domain. That is a security feature in the browser. You may have to try doing something in an iframe or something and checking that.

Answer (score 0):

jsonp wont do you much...

What you should do is create a local proxy easily on your server using your favorite language that'll simply load the url you pass to it and return the response code. Then, use jquery ajax to load up the proxy page with the url you want to test.

Comment: I don't have the option of the local proxy unfortunately (I only have certain customization options available on the server - some custom HTML places, and I can load JavaScript)..