# Check if YQL limits have been reached?

Tags: yql

Is there any way (other than having to add custom code) to check if my application has exceeded the YQL limits that are allowed? (Not sure if per application limit or the per IP limit applies in my case) I assume that all queries would fail after the limit is reached, but I'd like to be proactive in adding measures to prevent this from happening.

I am using YQL in a critical piece in the application and since a query is issued every few seconds, I suspect I might be nearing the limit.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, there currently is not a way to query for the current rate levels to see, for example, if you need to back off a bit.  Is your application signing the requests (i.e. are you using OAuth?); are you using the `/v1/public/yql` or `/v1/yql` URL?

Comment: @salathe - Thanks for the response. I am new to YQL and am not really sure if I can answer the question on if I am using /v1/public/yql or not. I am simply following the code snippet in the answered post here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119680/use-jquery-to-check-if-a-url-on-another-domain-is-404-or-not Please let me know your thoughts.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately error code 999 is also returned in other situations, so it is not a reliable indicator of reaching the hourly 10k limit.

**Example of response from Yahoo/YQL:**

```
HTTP/1.1 999 Unable to process request at this time -- error 999
Date: Sun, 07 Nov 2010 13:46:10 GMT
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 22:00:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-cache, private
Cache-Control: no-store
Pragma: no-cache
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Age: 0
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Server: YTS/1.17.21
```

I think it would be great if YQL could return a header field with the remaining YQL calls for per hour, like Twitter does.

**Relevant parts of the HTTP Response Header of the Twitter API:**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sun, 07 Nov 2010 13:52:18 GMT
X-RateLimit-Limit: 150
X-RateLimit-Remaining: 147
X-RateLimit-Class: api
X-Revision: DEV
X-RateLimit-Reset: 1289141505
```

Answer (score 3):

If you exceed the hourly allowance of 10k hits you will get back an error with the code 999 - write your code accordingly to avoid being blocked.